# Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: java, spring, jsf, tomcat

I'm trying to get Spring 3.2.3 project with PrimeFaces 3.5 to work on Tomcat 7.0.42, but I'm stuck on this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:350)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Here's my WebApplicationInitializer:

```
import javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String JSF_SERVLET_NAME = "jsf";
    private static final String JSF_SERVLET_MAPPING = "*.xhtml";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(Config.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic jsf = servletContext.addServlet(
                JSF_SERVLET_NAME, new FacesServlet());
        jsf.addMapping(JSF_SERVLET_MAPPING);
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD", "client");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }

}
```

I've tried to add `servletContext.addListener(new ConfigureListener());` line on my WebApplicationInitializer class but then the project sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

I'm using 2.2.1 version of jsf (jsf-api & jsf-impl).

Comment: I don't do Spring so I'm not sure whether this strange approach is right in Spring perspective, but didn't Spring advocate XML configuration over programmatic configuration? Just register the faces servlet in `web.xml` the usual way. As to the concrete problem, since JSF 2.1, JSF ships with its own `ServletContainerInitializer` who is supposed to already do this kind of stuff out the box. Apparently it's somehow conflicting with yours, effectively ending up with a duplicate faces servlet and faces listener registration and somehow a failure to properly register and/or find the right factories.

Comment: Ok, I just went from java config -> xml and it started to work, thanks.